# MS Access - Use Form to input data but generats incorrect data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

This is a simple database to track house rental income and payee. 
[image: The relationship of the database tables is here:]

A form is created to enter rental contract:

[image: New Rental Contract Form]

However, when I input the first dummy data, Access automatically generates an incorrect data row in my property List (The row with property ID = 0, Address = 1):
[image]

The renter list shows correctly except that the property ID is not assigned correctly (it should be assigned to 1, not 0):

[image]

Can someone please tell me why is this?

More details of the New Rental Contract Form:

[image]

Property Address is a combo box. The form does not show Property ID.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bind the combobox `property address` to `Property ID` on table  `Renter List`. Currently you are binding it to `Property Address`.  Also make sure that the combobox is set to 2 columns (Property ID ,Property Address). Make the column width(0) of first column to show only the address on the list.

Comment: You really should just bind the form to ONE table, and use a sub form for the related table of renter list, and in that sub form, the property id column should be a combo box that grabs the value from the 3rd table of property list. By attempting to bind the table to a query that joins multiple tables then you really  going have a hard time making this work, and you see multiple records for your main form -  you should only be able to jump to one record and then see + edit all the renter lists in a sub form.

Comment: Apart from previous good advice, the reason why Property_ID is 0 (zero) is because you use a default value 0 in Property_List table. You should change Property_ID into an autonumber column.

Comment: Yes I should have Property ID included in my combo box. Problem solved. Thank you all!